# Realising 2-legged OAuth with PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, api, oauth

i want to create an Api for my own mobile App to access data that is stored in a MySQL-Database. However i read a lot of articles about the 3-legged OAuth approach and i think this is not the solution i'am looking for. When i understand it correctly the 3-legged approach is more usable when for instance i create a new twitter client and want to use the twitter Api.

But my app is not a third party app, my app and the website incl. the database are from me. So i assume, that the user starts the app enters his user id and password, then the api has a function that checks whether userid/pw are correct and sends "true" as a result back to the app. The app then offers the user the possibility to access the functions for which a login is necessary. So the user should not be redirected to a website and "allow" the access to userid/pw.

If i understand it correctly the 2-legged approach is more likely for my purpose. But i am confused by this also. I assume that the user enters his id and pw, these credentials are looked up in the database by the web service a token will be looked up in the database for this user and will be send to the app. Additionally an app-token is saved in the app from the beginning and will be send with the request also. The app will save this user-token from the DB internally and will use this token everytime the user does something with the web service. With every request to the web service the token will be send to the service and the service checks whether the token is a valid one otherwise an error is send to the app.

I looked up this example:
http://code.google.com/p/oauth-php/wiki/ConsumerHowTo#Two-legged_OAuth

But there is nothing mentioned that the userid/pw from the user are looked up in the database...

Can anybody explain how i can solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Two legged OAuth is similar to Client-Server. It is a client app requesting full access to the data from a server. The client would have full access to all data allowed by it's credentials regardless of which user is accessing the client

Three legged OAuth is a User-Client-Server. It is a Client requesting to get access to the User's data from a server. The Client would only have access to that an authorized user's data (until the user revokes access).

Comment: Yes. But i my case i don't want to redirect the person who logs in via my app to any website to request a token. The user's credential should just be checked in the background and access in the app should be granted. The official Twitter- or Facebook app does not redirect you anywhere to accept anything when you enter your credentials....how can i do that?

Comment: If you control both the client and the server, then you should just create a client-server application where the user credentials are passed into the server behind the scenes from the client for authorization.

Comment: Are there any tutorials available that describe exactly that - how the server should react and how i can realize it with PHP...?